# Authenticating to the Google Analytics Core Reporting API for One Account

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I want to display the number of times a video has been viewed using the core reporting API via Javascript. However, the API is designed with OAuth, for building applications and not just logging into my account to get the event count.

Is there a way to login for just my account via Javascript?

Thanks,
Matthew.

Comment: Can you describe your requirement detailedly? What's problem if others account can be logged in?

Comment: I want to access the data that from my account every time, the site is commercial and there will be no need for the user to login to google analytics.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Google access tokens are "short-lived" and need to be refreshed every hour. [This Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825696/google-oauth-getting-refresh-token-using-javascript-generated-oauth-access-token) explains. Check out [embeddedanalytics.com](http://embeddedanalytics.com) (dislosure - I work with them). You could easily embed one of widgets in your site. And by scripting in a "filter" could access the visits for a particular page or custom event variable. –  M Schenkel 5 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a [Service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). To my knowledge you cant use a Service account with JavaScript due to security issues with the key file.

What you could try and do is to authenticate the script once using normal Oauth2 then save the refresh token to the file and hard code that into your script and send that.  But I wouldn't recommend it as then anyone that checks your script will also be able to access it.  So basically you have the same security issues you had with using a Service account.

As you can see doing what you are trying to do with JavaScript isn't really going to work. As you can see this is something I have also tried unsuccessfully in the past to do.  I recommend you try and do this with some kind of server sided scripting language, like PHP.